# Node.js regular expression non-capture group in semver

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, semantic-versioning

I'm trying to understand how semantic version works in nodejs (and npm). The git repo which hosts the regex used by nodejs is here https://github.com/sindresorhus/semver-regex, but I've copied the only two lines of code below.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = () => /\bv?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-[\da-z-]+(?:\.[\da-z-]+)*)?(?:\+[\da-z-]+(?:\.[\da-z-]+)*)?\b/ig;
```

This uses non-capture groups `(?:...)` for every group as far as I can tell. How does this work? The matches seem to return values despite not capturing anything. Am I missing a capture group? Is this something non-standard in nodejs?

Comment: It's completely wrong. It matches strings that do not conform to the [semver](https://semver.org) spec and if fails to match strings that are legal.

Answer (score -1):

It's obviously for [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) - it just return `true` or `false`;
For [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) first result will be value for ***full*** regex entrance. So it will be something like:

```js
// r = /\bv?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.(?:...
r.exec('1.0.1');// => Array [ "1.0.1" ];
```

And without `?:` as result we will have ***all groups*** as array values, like:

```js
// r = /\bv?(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(...
r.exec('1.0.1');// => Array(8) [ "1.0.1", "1", "0", "1", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

More than that, `exec` will always return result for regex, as first element (if it exist), even if you will have regex like:

```js
/(?:a)/.exec('a');// => Array [ "a" ]
```

I hope, I understood question correctly;

Comment: Yes, this helps tremendously. It appears that `exec` has an implicit capture group.

Comment: Yes, it returns true or false, but it's not a semver discriminator, it will yield false positives for nonconformant strings and false negatives for conformant strings.